# Link extractor is not able to get the paths beyond a certain path

Tags: scrapy

I need a bit help and your guidance on Scrapy.
My Start_Url is :: http://lighting.philips.co.uk/prof/
Have pasted my code below, which is able to get the links / paths till the below url.  But not going beyond that.  I need to go to each product's page, listed under the path below.  In the "productsinfamily" page the specific products are listed (perhaps within a java script).  My Crawler is not able to reach those individual product pages.

http://www.lighting.philips.co.uk/prof/led-lamps-and-tubes/led-lamps/corepro-ledbulb/productsinfamily/

Below is the code for the Crawl spider-

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ProductSearchSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "product_search"
    allowed_domains = ["lighting.philips.co.uk"]
    start_urls = ['http://lighting.philips.co.uk/prof/']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=
     (r'^https?://www.lighting.philips.co.uk/prof/led-lamps-and-tubes/.*', ),), 
     callback='parse_page', follow=True),)


    def parse_page(self, response):
        yield{'URL' : response.url}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the links are defined in javascript.

If you take a look at the html source, on line 3790 you can see a variable named `d75products` created. This is later used to populate a template and display the products.

The way I'd approach this would be to extract this data from the source and use the `json` module to load it. Once you have the data, you can do with it whatever you want.

Another way would be to use something (e.g. a browser) to execute the javascript, and then parse the resulting html. I do think that's unnecessary and overcomplicated though.

Comment: Thank You !! I will keep trying :(